# PlayN - Repeat image in background layer

Tags: java, playn

How I can repeat (X and Y) an image in  background layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this code does something similar:

```
final ImageLayer bgLayer = graphics().createImageLayer(bgImage);
bgLayer.setRepeatX(true);
bgLayer.setRepeatY(true);
graphics().rootLayer().add(bgLayer);
```