# ImageLayer setRepeatX and setRepeatY not working?

Tags: playn

I've tried setting the RepeatX/RepeatY for an ImageLayer to allow infinite translation.

From: [PlayN - Repeat image in background layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331695/playn-repeat-image-in-background-layer)

```
final ImageLayer bgLayer = graphics().createImageLayer(bgImage);
bgLayer.setRepeatX(true);
bgLayer.setRepeatY(true);
graphics().rootLayer().add(bgLayer);
```

Then I translate in my update loop. I've tried with both PNG and JPG. This does not seem to work? Am I missing anything obvious?

Thanks in advance,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was a bit confused on the function of setRepeat. This is used with tile based image. Not what I was looking for.

I will be managing this by hand.